# is there a way to delete only disabled breakpoints in xcode?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Is there a way to delete only disabled break points? 
I know how to delete all breakpoints or to disable all break points or to enable all breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting and deleting breakpoints is a manual process. So you cannot delete breakpoints on mass, but you can look through the breakpoint navigator and any that are grayed out are disabled breakpoints that you can then manually delete.

[image: Breakpoint list in project navigator]

Comment: :-( with 200 active break points that i want to retain, and 500 disabled breakpoints that i dont need, this is going to be hell. thanks though.